# Need button to disable and enable based on input fields

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend

I can't seem to get the button component here to enable after the input fields are filled, it simply starts disabled and then stays that way.

```
export default function Page() {
 const [newPassword, setNewPassword] = useState('');
 const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');
 const [isButtonDisabled, setIsButtonDisabled] = useState(true);


 useEffect(() => {
   setIsButtonDisabled(newPassword === '' || confirmPassword === '');
 }, [newPassword, confirmPassword])


 return (
   <>
     <Paper>
       <form
         onSubmit={(e) => {
           e.preventDefault();
           if (newPassword === confirmPassword) {
               console.log('Passwords match. Submitting form...');
             } else {
               console.log('Passwords do not match. Please try again.');
             }
         }}
         className="mb-0 mt-6 mb-6 space-y-4 rounded-lg p-4 shadow-lg sm:p-6 lg:p-8 bg-white"
       >
         <div className="text-center sm:text-left">
           <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold text-blue-900 sm:text-3xl">New Password</h1>
         </div>
         <div className="mb-4">
           <Input
               type="password"
               title="Enter New Password"
               value={newPassword}
               onChange={(e) => {
               setNewPassword(e.target.value);
               }}
           />
         </div>
         <div className="mb-6">
           <Input
               type="password"
               title="Confirm Password"
               value={confirmPassword}
               onChange={(e) => {
               setConfirmPassword(e.target.value);
               }}
           />
         </div>
         <div className="flex flex-col items-left space-y-4">
            <Button type="submit" disabled={isButtonDisabled} >
             Send
           </Button>
         </div>
       </form>
       <p className="text-center mt-6 text-gray-500 text-xs">&copy; 2024 Compass Center</p>
     </Paper>
   </>
 );
}
```

I changed my code around to utilize useEffect, thinking that would solve the issue, but it still does not work.

Comment: Not reproducible, when both the `newPassword` and `confirmPassword` state variables aren't empty strings, `isButtonDisabled` is set to false and the button is enabled. Here's the reproduction https://playcode.io/1775875

Answer (score 0):

you did not pay attention to this condition
setIsButtonDisabled(newPassword === '' || confirmPassword === '' || newPassword !== confirmPassword);

Answer (score 0):

```
setIsButtonDisabled(newPassword === '' || confirmPassword === '');
```

You set this in the useEffect, which monitors the two variables:

```
 }, [newPassword, confirmPassword])
```

So if one of the two variables changes the `setIsButtonDisabled` is triggered.

The problem is that if the `newPassword` is **empty** '' or the `confirmPassword` is **empty** '' *the button is disabled*.

**But if they are not empty strings the button is abled.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the onChange function, I think the param is value

```
onChange={value => set(value || "")}
```